# Measure volume using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, wav

Is it possible to measure decibels using ffmpeg or some other command line utility?  It does not exactly need to be decibels I just need peaks and values,  etc.  Some arbitrary measurement where I can tell when the decibel level has increased x% or something close.

Comment: See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volumedetect

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the free [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) tool which can do this.

Look at "Analysis" part, which has

```
stat: Enumerate audio peak & RMS levels, approx. freq., etc.
```